# Binary Indexed Tree: Why does "i + lowBit(i)" work?

Tags: algorithm, binary-indexed-tree

[image]

I know that if we want to update node with index `i`, we need to recursively update node `i = i + lowBit(i)` until the new value exceeds the size of the binary indexed tree.

My question is: how to prove that `i + lowBit(i)` can **cover all the nodes** we need to update? Is it possible that there's a node with index `j` which is not in the `i + lowBit(i)` chain and satisfies `j > i && j - lowBit(j) + 1 <= i`?

Thanks in advance.